# Create an .iso image of my complete Ubuntu 19.10 system

Tags: 19.10, iso

I'm going to update to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 19.10, and I would like to create an `.iso` image of my current system and burn it to a USB to restore it in my pc if anything goes wrong. I wanted to keep all my root files and programs installed in `/opt` and everywhere else.

Is that possible? How can I create that .iso image of my system? I know how to burn it to a USB, but I don't know how to create the `.iso` file.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: 
I found this, https://vitux.com/how-to-create-an-iso-file-in-ubuntu/ (Brasero), but I don't know how can I create an iso with every directory, just to have an iso with a clone of my pc. If someone can explain I will be very grateful.

Comment: Would you consider using Clonezilla to make an image on that USB, instead? https://clonezilla.org/

Comment: @K7AAY I've done it, but I'm not so familiar with clonezilla and images. I would prefer to create a .iso image and I thinks it's possible to do. It would be much easier and useful. I'm sure I'm not the only one thinking about it

Comment: Unfortunately it is *not* easier to create an iso file. It might be easier to create a compressed image file of the whole drive, but it might get quite big, if you want to keep all data files, and this process is slow compared to Clonezilla. I use Clonezilla and can recommend it too. Take your time to learn how to use it, and restore the image to another (fresh) drive, so that you know that the backup is good. Good luck :-)

Comment: @nobody support ended for that in Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Systemback and Distroshare can make ISOs. They work on Ubuntu 21.04. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/